# if condition in where clause of mysql query generating dynamically

Tags: mysql

Hi i am trying to write a query with if in where clause 
please suggest how can i do it my where condition is as follow

```
 IF(`page_type` ==1,
    `pages NOT LIKE '%ads/indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html%' 
  OR pages NOT LIKE '%ads/*%' OR pages NOT LIKE '%indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html/*%'` ,
   ` pages LIKE '%ads/indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html%'
  OR pages LIKE '%ads/*%' OR
     pages LIKE '%indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html/*%'` )
```

Full Query is

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `app_slides`
    WHERE  IF(`page_type` ==1, `pages NOT LIKE '%ads/indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html%'
              OR  pages NOT LIKE '%ads/*%'
              OR  pages NOT LIKE '%indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html/*%'` ,
                ` pages LIKE '%ads/indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html%'
              OR  pages LIKE '%ads/*%'
              OR  pages LIKE '%indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html/*%'` 
             )
```

Comment: Can you please show us your full query, thanks.

Comment: yes sir give me a min

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you want to do with the if statement.Is there an error if you try to execute the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case for this. Case statement work like this.

```
SELECT empno, ename, job
  FROM scott.emp
 WHERE (CASE WHEN job = 'MANAGER' THEN '1'  
         WHEN job = 'CLERK'   THEN '2' 
         ELSE '0'  END) IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: That is unnecessarily complex; it can be simplified to `WHERE job IN ('MANAGER', 'CLERK')` -- which will run faster.  However, since it does not seem even close to the query in the Question, I am downvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

`IF` works like this:

```
IF(<condition>, <value if true>, <value if false>)
```

So as an example

```
SELECT IF( 'a' = 'a', 1, 0 ); //will return 1
SELECT IF( 'a' = 'b', 1, 0 );//will return 0
```

Using `IF` in a `WHERE` query
The following example shows how to use `IF in a WHERE` query.

```
SELECT ...
WHERE ...
AND IF(myfield = 'somevalue', 1, 0) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be done in an if, but should be expressed using the logical operators.

```
select ... from ... where (`page_type` == 1 and ... )
or (`page_type` <>1 and ...)
```

you may optimize it by rewriting as a union instead of using or in the where criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You have one or two bugs that the other answers do not address...

```
   x NOT LIKE 'a'
OR x NOT LIKE 'b'
```

is always TRUE.  Hence, the first part of the `IF` will always succeed.  Perhaps you want

```
NOT (   x LIKE 'a'
     OR x LIKE 'b' )
```

specifically,

```
NOT (   `pages LIKE '%ads/indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html%' 
      OR pages LIKE '%ads/*%'
      OR pages LIKE '%indian-institute-of-technology-bombay.html/*%'` )
```

The other possible bug:

```
ads/*
```

Is that actually what you are expecting?  Note that `*`, when used in `LIKE` is not the same as when used in `RLIKE`.

It does not really matter whether you use `IF`, `CASE`, or `page_type == 1 and (...)` -- each will perform approximately equally.  And each will come up with the desired results (after fixing the bug(s) I pointed out).  And each will be slow -- that is, each will do a full table scan.  This is for 2 reasons:

- Leading wild cards (`LIKE '%...'`) does not optimize well.
- `OR` does not optimize well.  (And changing to `UNION` is useful only if you get rid of all the `ORs` *and* the leading wildcards).